# Why is Class not appearing in blue in Xcode?

Tags: iphone

I have a class called PlayingCard. I am trying to use it in a class called PlayingCardDeck.

I have imported PlayingCard.h in PlayingCardDeck.h

```
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@interface PlayingCardDeck : Deck

@end
```

When I try to call a class method in PlayingCardDeck.m it doesn't appear in blue. XCode does see the class in autocomplete but it is not in blue when selected. In this example, I am trying to call the init method.But, I get the error expected expression as if it XCode does not know what the PlayingCard class is. The error for the calls to card.rank = and card.suit= don't work either because I believe that PlayingCard is not being recognized. This doesn't make sense as I have defined the class and imported it into PlayCardDeck.h Can someone shed some insight? Thanks in advance.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Deck.h"
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@interface PlayingCardDeck : Deck

@end


#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"

@implementation PlayingCardDeck

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        for(NSString *suit in [PlayingCard validSuits])
            for(NSUInteger rank =1; rank <= 10; rank++)
                PlayingCard *card = [[PlayingCard alloc] init];
                card.rank = rank;
        card.suit = suit;

    }
}
```

@end

```
@interface PlayingCard : Card

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* suit;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger rank;

+(NSArray *) validSuits;
//+(NSUInteger) maxRank;


@end
```

Comment: Which class method are you calling on `PlayingCardDeck`? Have you `@synthesize`d the properties? Does it crash at runtime, or is it giving you compiler errors?

Answer (score 5):

Your lack of `{` and `}` in those for loops give you trouble.

This code

```
if (self) {
    for(NSString *suit in [PlayingCard validSuits])
        for(NSUInteger rank =1; rank <= 10; rank++)
            PlayingCard *card = [[PlayingCard alloc] init];
            card.rank = rank;
    card.suit = suit;

}
```

Actually mean this

```
if (self) {
    for(NSString *suit in [PlayingCard validSuits]) {
        for(NSUInteger rank =1; rank <= 10; rank++) {
            PlayingCard *card = [[PlayingCard alloc] init]; 
        }
    }
    card.rank = rank;
    card.suit = suit;
}
```

Now you can clearly see that the card variable is out of scope.

---

You should add `{` and `}` to explicitly define the scope of the for loops like this

```
if (self) {
    for(NSString *suit in [PlayingCard validSuits]) {
        for(NSUInteger rank =1; rank <= 10; rank++) {
            PlayingCard *card = [[PlayingCard alloc] init];
            card.rank = rank;
            card.suit = suit;
        }
    }
}
```